# Can't get Rails Action Text in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, richtext, actiontext

When I save a model with action text, the content saves to the database, but it's not accessible through the console.

I have a Section model with `has_rich_text :content`

When I try to create a new record, it creates a rich text association, but the body is always blank.

```
section.content = '<p>Hello world</p>'
section.save
=> true
section.content
=> #<ActionText::RichText id: 6, name: "content", body: #<ActionText::Content " ">, record_type: "Section", record_id: 2, created_at: "2020-05-07 13:49:58", updated_at: "2020-05-07 14:00:36">
section.content.to_s
=> " "
section.content.body
=> #<ActionText::Content " ">
```

It properly sets in the database, and the value is being accessed by my code in a serializer and sending the proper `content`. However, I would like to gain access to this content through the console.

Comment: what does `section.content?` return when you type it in the console ?

Comment: does `section.content.to_s` return the string you stored in content ?

Comment: `NoMethodError (undefined method \`content?' for #<Section:0x00007ff459fbc340>)
Did you mean?  content
               content=`

Comment: I did notice that it is actually setting it in the database, but I can't gain access to the content from the console. Instead of returning the HTML, it just returns a blank `ActionText::Content` class

Comment: `to_s` just returns `" "`( a string with one space), not what is in the database

Comment: Have you found out the solution?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like there is a problem with ActionText when using API only setup.

**See:** https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/39266

The following code returns `" "` which should not be the case.

```
section.content.to_s
 => " "

section.content.body.to_s
 => " "
```

As an alternative, you can use the following:

```
section.content.body.to_html
 => "<p>Hello world</p>"
```

**EDIT:**
I just noticed that the OP of this question and OP of the issue in Rails repository is the same. I will just put the answer to this for visibility as I encountered this problem myself and took me a while to found the issue in the Rails repository.